# Django request.user not working when using auth_user_model in models.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am using the User model (which is a custom one) in my models.py by import settings and getting it through the AUTH_USER_MODEL but it seems like in my views that the request.user is not recognize as an instance of the user class.

Here is the model

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name="administrators",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    people = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

HERE is the logic in the views

```
def create_site(request):
user = request.user
print(user)
form = CreateSiteForm(
    request.POST or None,
    initial={
        "admin": user,
    },
)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return redirect("projects")

context = {
    "form": form,
}
return render(request, "tracking/create-site.html", context)
```

Here is the error from the terminal

```
       return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\Papis\Desktop\Dev\projects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 170, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Papis\Desktop\Dev\projects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 374, in full_clean
    self._post_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Papis\Desktop\Dev\projects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 408, in _post_clean
    self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
  File "C:\Users\Papis\Desktop\Dev\projects\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 63, in construct_instance
    f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
  File "C:\Users\Papis\Desktop\Dev\projects\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 910, in save_form_data
    setattr(instance, self.name, data)
  File "C:\Users\Papis\Desktop\Dev\projects\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 215, in __set__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot assign "'papis'": "Site.admin" must be a "User" instance.
```

The request.user returns the username of the user. I am wondering what is the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance......

Comment: As a wild guess, did you try passing user.pk instead?

Comment: Not sure this will help your problem but there is a standard way of getting custom user models. from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model gives you a function that returns the configured user model. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: For foreign keys, Django form expects a primary key of the object. Try passing the user ID.

Comment: If I do a get_user_model I am getting a circular import issue don't even know why let me pass the id and see if it will work.

Comment: Maybe under form.is_valid it might be worth printing the type of user, print(type(form.cleaned_data["admin"])). It might be returning an int of the user's ID or a string of the user's name.

Comment: I think the problem is the initial value that I am paasing to the admin input because nothing is printed after I tried to print the type if the form is valid. Don't understand why since it is User instance for sure.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of the User in the models

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

and change your views to this

```
user=request.user.id
```